# Pointer/Dynamic Memory Allocation Function Error (Xcode to Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, xcode, function, pointers

I have just recently learned about pointers in class, and have an assignment where the program allows a user to implement both pointers and dynamic memory allocation by testing four functions.

The only place where I am having issues is in the last function, subArray. This should display only a certain part of the array specified by the start index and length values set.

This program works fine on Xcode, giving the correct output and returning 0. This is the output on Xcode:

```
Testing isSorted: 

Test data for array 1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Expected result: true 
Actual result: true
Test data for array 2: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
Expected result: false
Actual result: false
Test data for array 3: 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 
Expected result: false
Actual result: false


Testing chain for 15.46 inches: 

Expected result: 15.46 feet: 4 inches: 5
Actual result: 15.46 feet: 4 inches: 5


Testing grow: 

Test data: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Expected result: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 
Actual result: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 


Testing subArray: 

Test data: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Start: 5 Length: 4
Expected result: 6 7 8 9 
Actual result: 6 7 8 9 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

However, I have to compile on Linux for full credit, and am receiving the following issue when I run the code on Linux:

```
Error in `./exe': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000678060 ***
```

The output is the exact same as Xcode except for the very last "Actual Results : " row within testing the subArray function.

```
Testing subArray: 

Test data: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Start: 5 Length: 4
Expected result: 6 7 8 9 
*** Error in `./run': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000678060 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c619)[0x7f1da7cd3619]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d1bb)[0x7f1da7cd41bb]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7dba5)[0x7f1da7cd4ba5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x4c)[0x7f1da7cd710c]
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_Znwm+0x1d)[0x7f1da85911bd]
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_Znam+0x9)[0x7f1da85912b9]
./run[0x401376]
./run[0x401327]
./run[0x401097]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f1da7c78c05]
./run[0x4009c9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:2e 9715713                            /home/Students/klw231/run
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 00:2e 9715713                            /home/Students/klw231/run
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:2e 9715713                            /home/Students/klw231/run
00678000-006bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f1da0000000-7f1da0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1da0021000-7f1da4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1da7c57000-7f1da7e0f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 67288141                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f1da7e0f000-7f1da800f000 ---p 001b8000 fd:00 67288141                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f1da800f000-7f1da8013000 r--p 001b8000 fd:00 67288141                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f1da8013000-7f1da8015000 rw-p 001bc000 fd:00 67288141                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f1da8015000-7f1da801a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1da801a000-7f1da802f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 67161030                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f1da802f000-7f1da822e000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 67161030                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f1da822e000-7f1da822f000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 67161030                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f1da822f000-7f1da8230000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 67161030                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f1da8230000-7f1da8331000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 67657412                   /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f1da8331000-7f1da8530000 ---p 00101000 fd:00 67657412                   /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f1da8530000-7f1da8531000 r--p 00100000 fd:00 67657412                   /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f1da8531000-7f1da8532000 rw-p 00101000 fd:00 67657412                   /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f1da8532000-7f1da861b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 67150761                   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f1da861b000-7f1da881b000 ---p 000e9000 fd:00 67150761                   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f1da881b000-7f1da8823000 r--p 000e9000 fd:00 67150761                   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f1da8823000-7f1da8825000 rw-p 000f1000 fd:00 67150761                   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f1da8825000-7f1da883a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1da883a000-7f1da885b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 67150948                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f1da8a47000-7f1da8a4c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1da8a58000-7f1da8a5b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1da8a5b000-7f1da8a5c000 r--p 00021000 fd:00 67150948                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f1da8a5c000-7f1da8a5d000 rw-p 00022000 fd:00 67150948                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f1da8a5d000-7f1da8a5e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc48603000-7ffc48624000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc4867b000-7ffc4867d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Actual result: Aborted
```

I know something has to be going wrong with a pointer somewhere within the function, but I have tried many possible solutions and want a better idea of what I can do to fix this. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


// Function prototypes

bool isSorted(int *arr, int size);
double chain(int totalInches, int *feet, int *inches);
int *grow(int *arr, int size);
int *subArray(int *arr, int start, int length);
int *duplicateArray(int *arr, int size);
void showArray( int *arr, int size);


int main()
{
int *arr = NULL;      //to dynamically allocate an array


// Test isSorted

 int size = 8;
 int testArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
 cout << endl;
 cout << "Testing isSorted: \n" << endl;
 cout << "Test data for array 1: ";
    showArray(testArray, size);
 cout << "\nExpected result: true " << endl;
 cout << "Actual result: " << boolalpha << isSorted(testArray, size);

 int testArray2[]= {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
 cout << "\nTest data for array 2: ";
    showArray(testArray2, size);
 cout << "\nExpected result: false" << endl;
 cout << "Actual result: " << boolalpha << isSorted(testArray2, size);

 int testArray3[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8};
 cout << "\nTest data for array 3: ";
    showArray(testArray3, size);
 cout << "\nExpected result: false" << endl;
 cout << "Actual result: " << boolalpha << isSorted(testArray3, size);
 cout << endl;


// Test chain

 int totalInches = 53;
 int inches;
 int feet;
 double expected = chain(totalInches, &feet, &inches);

 cout << "\n\nTesting chain for " << expected << " inches: " << endl;
 cout << "\nExpected result: " << expected << " feet: "<< feet << " inches: " << inches << endl;
 cout << "Actual result: " << chain(totalInches, &feet, &inches)
 << " feet: " << feet << " inches: " << inches << "\n" << endl;
 cout << endl;


// Test grow

 int testArray4[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
 size = 9;  // Size is now larger
 cout << "Testing grow: " << endl;
 cout << "\nTest data: ";
    showArray(testArray4, size);
 cout << "\nExpected result: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 " << endl;
 cout << "Actual result: ";
    showArray(grow(testArray4, size),size*2);
 cout << endl;


// Test subArray

 int start = 5;
 int length = 4;

 cout << "\n\nTesting subArray: " << endl;
 cout << "\nTest data: ";
    showArray(testArray4, size);
 size = length;
 cout << "\nStart: " << start << " " << "Length: " << length << endl;
 cout << "Expected result: 6 7 8 9 " << endl;
 cout << "Actual result: ";

 int *c = subArray(testArray4, start, length);
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    cout << *(c + i) << " ";
}
 cout << endl;
delete [] c;
c = NULL;

delete arr;      // Releasing dynamically allocated space
arr = NULL;

return 0;
}
//************************************************************************
// bool isSorted: determines whether or not elements in the array are sorted
//
// int *arr: A pointer to a dynamically allocated array
// int size: The number of elements in the array
// returns:  This function returns either a true or false boolean value.
//************************************************************************

bool isSorted(int *arr, int size)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < size - 1; index ++)
    {
        if(*(arr + index) > *(arr + index + 1))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


//************************************************************************
// double chain: takes in values from main and performs math operations on them
//
// int totalInches: Adds together feet and inches
// int *feet: A pointer to it's respective value in main
// int *inches: A pointer to it's respective value in main
// returns: This function returns the result as an integer pointer.
//************************************************************************

double chain (int totalInches, int *feet, int *inches)
{

        *feet = totalInches / 12;
        *inches = totalInches % 12;

    return *(feet) * 3.49 + *(inches) * 0.30;
}


//************************************************************************
// int *grow: creates a new array twice the size of the argument array
//
// int *arr: A pointer to a dynamically allocated array
// int size: The number of elements in the array
// returns: This function returns the new array as an integer pointer.
//************************************************************************

int *grow (int *arr, int size)
{
    int *newArray;
    newArray = new int[size*2];      //allocate new array

    for(int i=0; i<(size*2); i+=1)
    {
        *(newArray + i) = *(arr + i / 2);
        *(newArray + i + 1) = *(arr + i / 2);
    }

    return newArray;
}


//************************************************************************
// int *subArray:
//
// int *arr: A pointer to a dynamically allocated array
// int start: Sets the starting element to display
// int length: Sets how long the array segment to display is
// returns: This function returns the result as an integer pointer.
//************************************************************************

int *subArray(int *arr, int start, int length)
{
    int *result = duplicateArray(arr + start, length);

    return result;
}


//************************************************************************
// int *duplicateArray: copies array and returns only selected values
//
// int *arr: A pointer to a dynamically allocated array
// int size: The number of elements in the array
// returns: This function returns the new array as an integer pointer.
//************************************************************************

int *duplicateArray (int *arr, int size)
{

    int *newArray;
    if (size <= 0)         //size must be positive
        return NULL;       //NULL is 0, an invalid address

    newArray = new int [size];  //allocate new array

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        newArray[index] = arr[index];  //copy to new array

    return newArray;
}


//************************************************************************
// void showArray: displays the contents of the array
//
// int *arr: A pointer to a dynamically allocated array
// int size: The number of elements in the array
// returns: This function is void and does not return a value.
//************************************************************************

void showArray( int *arr, int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(arr + i) << " ";
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: *This program works fine on Xcode* -- Doesn't really mean much.  If your program fails to work on another compiler, computer, etc. the program is just lucky to "work" on Xcode.  More than likely your program has undefined behavior going on, and the undefined behavior on Xcode is "it works".

Comment: `showArray(grow(testArray4, size), size * 2);` -- This is a memory leak.  The `grow` returns a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, yet there is no way to deallocate that memory since the return value of `grow` is sent as a parameter and is lost forever.

Comment: I fixed it by creating separate pointers for each function. It now works on Linux @PaulMcKenzie thank you!

Comment: Remember that any time you call `new` you're responsible for the corresponding `delete`. The `grow` method allocates and returns a new array but it doesn't delete the old one, a textbook case memory leak. You can side-step a lot of this by using modern C++ facilities like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Xcode is an IDE - Linux is a OS kernel... Your title doesn’t make sense...

Answer (score 0):

This assignment is, unfortunately, one of those that tries to teach C++ while ending up teaching some mutant variant of C. The reason for your problem appears to be this chunk of code:

```
int *c = subArray(testArray4, start, length);
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    cout << *(c + i) << " ";
}
```

The array returned is only of length `length` but the iterator there goes up to `size`, so it walks off the end of the allocation and ends up triggering undefined behaviour. It's invalid. The "fix" is this:

```
int *c = subArray(testArray4, start, length);
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    cout << *(c + i) << " ";
}
```

I was able to find this problem by deleting a lot of the code that wasn't part of the problem. When the compiler complained that `size` wasn't defined I knew that's what the issue was, it was a value from other tests being used inappropriately here. This is why keeping your code as organized as possible is key, mistakes can creep in when you're not able to see things clearly.

A better approach to this would be to define a `class` for the array plus associated iterators to help navigate through it. This is not only less messy and error-prone, but as a bonus it makes it fully compatible with the existing C++ container tools in the Standard Library. Should you go on to do this professionally knowing how to make your own Standard Library compatible class is a very important skill.

I'm disappointed that so few courses ever think to do that.